# Can processing this Async socket be done more efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous

I am receiving a large numbers of messages and I would like to make my ReceivedCallBack more efficient.

I am using some convenient string handling - but is there a faster way?

```
    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket socket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        public string SessionID()
        {
            return socket.Handle.ToString();
        }
    }

public void ReceivedCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket socket = state.socket;

        try
        {
            int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));


                string[] contents = state.sb.ToString().Split('@');
                int delimCount = state.sb.ToString().Count(x => x == '@');

                for (int d = 0; d < delimCount; d++)
                {
                    if (contents[d] != "")
                        OnMessage(state, contents[d]);
                }

                if (!state.sb.ToString().EndsWith("@"))
                {
                    state.sb.Clear();
                    state.sb.Append(contents[contents.Count() - 1]);

                }
                else
                {
                    state.sb.Clear();

                }

                socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallBack), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // If no data was recieved then the connection is probably dead
                OutputWriteLine("Client " + state.SessionID() + " disconnected");
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unusual error during Receive!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need `delimCount`, just use `foreach (string content in contents) { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content)) OnMessage(state, content); }`

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental problem here: you are leaving the socket w/o a buffer while you're processing the current one. The kernel *might* drop packets, leading to retries. For high throughput you should post multiple buffers and re-post new, empty buffers immediately as your receive completes, before processing the completed one. Now *that* being said, achieving correct processing with multiple buffers is *very* hard, as you must keep track of the order posted and you must handle incomplete messages carefully (you cannot repost a partially filled buffer for the 'rest' of the message because there is already a buffer posted). Read the articles linked at [High Performance Windows programs](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/) for more details.

Now, with the code you have: profile it. Start with [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). I suspect you'll find the usual culprits (eg. allocations in `string.Split()`) but I suggest you measure yourself, find the bottlenecks and only then make changes.

For your string processing, read this classic: [why GNU grep is fast](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) (altough searching for a single `@` is not going to be so impactful using [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)). If possible, consider changing the protocol to something more parsing friendly (eg. binary [proto buff](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)).

Comment: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/fast-text-search-with-boyer-moore

Answer (score 1):

The string processing is indeed very inefficient. Allocations, LINQ, and quadratic processing cost per message. Also, calling `sb.ToString` 3 times is not going to help.

Put the app under full load and profile this code to see whether it needs to be optimized or not. If yes, you probably should apply some easy fixes first and address the things that I mentioned.

In general you probably should not write your own (ASCII-based) network protocol. Simply use something that is ready-made such as WCF, HTTP or protobuf.